# Configuring mount options for Gnome/Nautilus Auto mounter

Tags: gnome, ntfs, fedora, nautilus

I use Fedora 13 with Gnome. I have two NTFS partions that are listed by Nautilus in the pane on the left hand side (in browser mode). When I click on any one of those drives, it prompts me for the root password and mounts the drive.
Is there some way I configure this behavior so that I can select whether I want to mount the partition as read-only or read-write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It will always use the options [given by hal](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=40951).